# can I change the style of the ion-searchbar angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I'm making an angular ionic project. But I want to customize the style of the ion-searchbar. On the template of the ionic, the search bar icon is located on the left side. I want to change the position of the icon, I wanna move it to the right side. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Add this styles to your global.css file.

```
.searchbar-md .searchbar-search-icon{
    right: 47px !important; //Adjust right position as your need
    left: auto !important;
}
```

Adjust search bar padding also to improve the alignments.

```
.searchbar-md .searchbar-input{
  padding: 6px 9px; !important // Adjust as your need 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ionic 5, `global.css` file

```
ion-searchbar {
     /* overall styles here */
    .searchbar-input-container {
        /* inner input styles here */
        input{
           /* input element styles here */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can I just put the styles in the local scss component file?

Comment: I've only ever used it globally. Component scss will rename the class for namespace reasons  - even though these are not class based styles, there still might be an issue.. not sure.

Comment: unfortunately it became overridden because I'm also using tailwindcss

Comment: Did you try it anyways? It should work in your local component scss file because it's not dependent on class names